# Blue screen of death windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssd

Recently my windows 10 posted blue screen of death. Tried rolling back updates, restore points, advanced system repair with no success. I have a previous used ssd with windows which booted successfully.
Is there away I can repair the damaged windows operating system whilst using my current old working ssd?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, though don't hold too much hope onto it; But first, you should boot with the old ssd and connect the new ssd to the computer while the computer is booted up. This can be done by putting the new ssd into an external hdd case and connect to a USB port.

Then remember the drive letter of your new ssd, replace the X: with the actual drive letter when you run it(i.e. D:)
First, open Explorer, open "This PC", if openning Explorer doesn't show "This PC", in the left pane, find and click "This PC", check which drive is your external drive by either using volume name or volume size, remember its drive letter.

Open elevated Command Prompt by using either one of the three methods:

1, Task Manger

Ctrl+Alt+Del to bring up security options, click "Task Manager", click "File"->"Run new task"->type cmd->click "Create this task with administrative privileges" checkbox->"OK"

2, Create a desktop shortcut

right click on Desktop->"New"->"Shortcut"->type %comspec%->press "Enter"->press "Enter", then right click on cmd.exe.lnk->"Properties"->"Advanced..."->check "Run as administrator"->"OK"->"Apply"->"OK" (if there is a pop up window just hit "OK"), then double click the shortcut. By using this method you can just double click on the shortcut on desktop the next time you want to run cmd, or drag it to taskbar and you only need single click to run it.

3, use run menu

Win+R->type cmd->Ctrl+Shift+Enter

First of all, run:

```
chkdsk /f /r /x X:
```

to check for any filesystem errors and bad sectors, and if bad sectors(not filesystem errors) are found, buy a new ssd...

Then if no bad sectors, run these commands:

```
dism /image:X:\ /cleanup-image /scanhealth
dism /image:X:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

The dism commands will fix system file corruptions if there is any, outside of that, it isn't very helpful, BSoD's are more likely related to registry issues than system file corruption, so if these commands do not fix the issue, my advice: reinstall Windows onto the new ssd, follow these steps:

First, you need the latest Windows 10 ISO, which can be downloaded from official site for free, if you don't know how to change UserAgents, use your phone; Access this site:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO
Then you should be able to know what to do by yourself: "Select edition" "Confirm" "Select the product language" choose one, "Confirm", then you can choose between 32-bit or 64-bit versions, my advice: choose 64-bit one.

Now don't tap that button! You don't want to download it to your phone, do you?
Tap and hold download button and tap "copy link address", now you have to figure out how to send the link to your PC, you can save it as a txt and connect your phone to your computer via USB.

Then download the image, sorry there isn't much I can help, but it's easy, figure it out yourself.

Now once downloaded, you should be able to mount it by simply double clicking, remember its letter, here I use H: to represent it, replace H: when you run the commands:

```
diskpart
list disk
```

To list your disks, now disk 0 should be your old ssd, find which is your new ssd by size, here I use "disk 1" to denote it;

```
select disk 1
clean
create partition primary
format fs=ntfs
assign letter=X
quit
```

The above makes sure your new ssd is clean, now your new ssd's letter is a literal X:, so don't replace it.

Then open H:\Sources\install.wim with any compression software, you will see lots of folders with numbers as names, these are indexes, corresponding to different editions, sorry I can't help you, you have to figure out which one you want, remember its index, here I use 1:

```
Dism /apply-image /imagefile:H:\Sources\install.wim /index:1 /ApplyDir:X:\
BCDboot X:\Windows /s X: /f ALL
```

The above commands will install Windows to the new ssd and make it bootable, restart and boot into the new ssd to finish installation.